# How often are fakes assemblies generated?

Tags: microsoft-fakes

Sometimes when I build my test project it takes a significantly longer time than usual. I've noticed whenever it does take a long time it's because the *.Fakes.dll assemblies are being generated. But why is it not generating fakes every time I rebuild my project? What determines if the Fakes assemblies will be generated?

Comment: Hi Nick, Did you figure out your answer yet? I have the same question!

Comment: No, it remains a mystery to me.